# How to configure LDAPCP correctly?

Tags: claims, ldap

I just configured LDACP *.wsp package for searching and resolving users from external LDAP in SharePoint 2016.
Next I started checking how it works but when started searching I got results as below:
(Entries with (EmailAddress) prefix and without)

[image]

My claims are configured as follows:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is to have only entries without (EmailAddress) prefix but with possibility to search via email and accountname.
What also is imported once user is resolved I would like to add him to the group with account like: i:0g.t|users|S-1-5-21-3286968501-24975625-1618430583
So SID instead of windowsaccountname.

Thank you help!